# Easier way to reduce this code

Tags: c#, function

I have the following code

```
SetField("TextField1", ( item.FirstName == null || item.FirstName[0] == null)
                      ? ""  : item.FirstName[0].Value);
SetField("TextField2", ( item.MiddleName == null || item.MiddleName[0] == null)
                     ? "" : item.MiddleName[0].Value);
SetField("TextField3", ( item.LastName == null || item.LastName[0] == null)
                     ? "" : item.LastName[0].Value);
................
like this 50-60 lines
```

Is there a way I can write a function and pass in parameters to reduce this code

(say for example )

```
void Helper(string fieldName, somethinghere )
{
   SetField(fieldName,usesomethinghere);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `item.FirstName` ? I best guess is a `char?[]` which seems rather absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the data type of the properties of `item`, but assuming it's `T`, if you define (overload):

```
void SetField(string fieldName, T[] itemProperty)
{
    SetField(fieldName,
        itemProperty == null || itemProperty[0] == null ? "" : itemProperty[0].Value);
}
```

then your 50-60 lines can be reduced to:

```
SetField("TextField1", item.FirstName);
SetField("TextField2", item.MiddleName);
SetField("TextField3", item.LastName);
...
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes Exactly. Also is there a way I can put the field mapping in a 2-dimensional array , so I can loop thru it and call this function
something like

`code`
    array[][] arr=new [][]

            { "TextField1", item.FirstName ,
              "TextField2", item.LastName 
            }

    or even better if the instantiation is 
           { "TextField1", "FirstName" ,
             "TextField2", "LastName" 
           }

and do 
   foreach(var something in arr)
   {
      SetField(arr[0][0], arr[0][1]);
   }
`code`

Comment: I don't know the 2D array solution. I'm more of a Lisp guy. I too would like to see how this is done in C#.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a new read-only property in the Item class?

Something like:

```
public String FirstName_for_display {
    get {
        if(FirstName == null || FirstName[0] == null)
            return "";
        return FirstName[0].Value;
    }
}
```

And called your SetField with something like:

```
SetField("TextField1", item.FirstName_for_display)
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. There is no issue in this code, but want to see if there is a way that I can call a function with a string which defines "TextField1"  and takes another property ( this is the tough part for me ) and calls SetField(str1,arg2).

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
Private void fieldsSetter(string[] fieldnames, object[] items)
{

    for(int s=0; s<fieldnames.Count(); s++)
    {
        SetField(fieldnames[s], (((item)items).FirstName == null || ((item)items).FirstName[0] == null) ? ""  : ((item)items).FirstName[0].Value);
    }

}
```

not tested though....